# Is it ok to initialize a util class before using its methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns, static-methods

Is it a design smell if I have to call the init method of a util class before  I can use its methods ?  Is the following code a bad design for util class ?

```
public class MyUtils {
    private static MyObject myObject;

    public static void init(MyObject testObject) {
        myObject = testObject;
    }

    public static void closePDFWindow(String myString) {
        myObject.displaySomthing(myString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is very bad design. Having to call the `init` once, sharing that arbitrary states with other callers of the `MyUtils` class, having everything `static`, not preventing multiple calls to `init`, etc.

Comment: A static block might be better suited.

Comment: @Kartik But maybe `MyObject` isn't available on startup

Comment: A class like this that holds state (`myObject`) shouldn't use statics.

Comment: Why don't you pass the desired object directly in the `static` method? Like `public static void closePDFWindow(String myString, MyObject myObject)` and make the class without a `static` attribute?

Comment: @deHaar probably he have multiple methods using it

Comment: Can you show `MyObject`? how is it initialized?

Comment: @deHaar This is a design I found in a code. I was bit confused with this design, since you get a "nullpointer" if you don't call the init method before calling the other methods.  And yes there are multiple methods using this.

Comment: @philjack OK, then it's just bad design…

Answer (score 1):

That would be called "temporal coupling" as there's an implicit relationship between the two methods, you have to call the first one then the second.

So, you can avoid this using ["Static Initialization Blocks"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) and a factory class that initialize "testObject"